# Linked list reversal program is not working

Tags: c, linked-list

I am not able to identify any error in my program.
But when i run it,it is taking the inputs infinitely.At first i thought there must be some issues with the pointer assignments but everything seems fine.
The program is just taking inputs infinitely.

The reversing function is defined by rev().It doesn't take any parameters bcoz
head is defined globally.

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct node
{
  int n;
  struct node *next;
};

struct node *head;

//void beg(int);
//void nth(int,int);
//void delbe();
//void del(int);
void rev ();



int main()
{
    int i, s, x, y, z, l;
    i = 0;
    struct node* temp;
    struct node* temp1;
    struct node* cur;
    head = NULL;
    scanf("%d", &s);
    while (i < s) {
        scanf("%d", &x);
        if (head == NULL) {
            temp = (struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
            temp->n = x;
            temp->next = NULL;
            head = temp;
            temp1 = head;
        }
        else {
            temp = (struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
            temp->n = x;
            temp->next = NULL;
            temp1->next = temp;
            temp1 = temp1->next; //Assigning the next node.i.e. NULL value
        }
        i = i + 1;
    }
    cur = head;
    printf("Before\n");
    while (cur != NULL) {
        printf("%d\n", cur->n);
        cur = cur->next;
    }

    rev();
    printf("After\n");
    cur = head;
    while (cur != NULL) {
        printf("%d\n", cur->n);
        cur = cur->next;
    }
    return 0;
}

void rev()
{
    struct node* prev;
    struct node* temp;
    struct node* cur;
    cur = head;
    temp = cur;
    while (temp != NULL) {
        if (cur == head) {
            prev = NULL;
            cur->next = prev;
        }
        else {
            cur = temp->next;
            prev = temp;
            temp = temp->next;
            cur->next = prev;
            if (temp == NULL) {
                head = cur;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have an infinite loop in this while loop

```
while (temp != NULL)
    {
      if (cur == head)
    {
      prev = NULL;
      cur->next = prev;
    }
    //..
```

because `cur` is still equal to `head` after the if statement. So the control always is passed to this if statement within the loop.

The simplest way to reverse the list is to form a new list inserting nodes of the original list in the new list.

For example

```
void rev()
{
    if ( head != NULL && head->next != NULL )
    {
        struct node *new_head = NULL;

        while ( head != NULL )
        {
            struct node *current = head;
            head = head->next;
            current->next = new_head;
            new_head = current;
        }

        head = new_head;
    }
}
```

Comment: Note: the`if()...` is not needed.

Comment: @wildplasser In this case the declaration of new_head will be inside a block where it is not used.:)